# React component rendering issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There are three buttons home, about and help and added three event handler function that when user click on each button, user should see the expected section. So, here initial state is set to "home".
Problem is when I click about button for the first time it updated correctly and console message is print, but if I click again the about button it again show console message. Also, React Dev Tool tells that component is rendered for clicking the first time.

```
import { useState } from "react"

export default function Button() {
console.log('Button component rendered');
const [section, setSection] = useState('Home')
    function home() {
        setSection('Home')
    }
    function about() {
        setSection('About')
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={home}>Home</button>
                    <button onClick={about}>About</button>
                </div>
                <p>{section}</p>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

I found that whenever a state changes the component is re-rendered to update the UI, So,for the first time it renders ok because state is changes from "Home" to "About". But for the second time clicking on the about button it shouldn't print the console message, but why this is happening, I am very confuse about it...

Comment: can you please let me know from where you getting `profile` variable?

Comment: oh''' sorry...I have forgot to update, but anyway, I am not finding the answer which i have expecting.

Comment: can you tell in one line what you exactly want.

Comment: you only want to log in console when state is changed. if i'm right ?

Comment: @sarfarajshah Yes, it should only log message in the console when the state changes. This is confusing me since morning

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is that the component is getting re-rendered every time you click on the every button. This is because the state is getting updated every time you click the button, and when the state changes, React re-renders the component.

To solve this issue, you can use the useEffect hook to log the console message only once when the component mounts.And you can use a condition so that if the new value is equal to the previous value, the state will not be updated. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
 import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
    export default function Button() {

      console.log('Button component rendered');
      const [section, setSection] = useState('Home')

  

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Button component mounted');
      }, [])

 

      function home() {
        if (section !== 'Home') {
          setSection('Home')
        }
      }

  

    function about() {
        if (section !== 'About') {
          setSection('About')
        }
      }

 
function help() {
        if (section !== 'Help') {
          setSection('Help')
        }
      }

      return (
        <>
          <div>
            <div>
              <button onClick={home}>Home</button>
              <button onClick={about}>About</button>
              <button onClick={help}>Help</button>
            </div>
            {section === 'Home' && <p>Home section</p>}
            {section === 'About' && <p>About section</p>}
            {section === 'Help' && <p>Help section</p>}
          </div>
        </>
      )
    }
```

Comment: Terrible design. Just create one function and pass text as argument.

Comment: I just modified her code a bit so that he can understand the subject. Otherwise, these repetitive functions were not necessary.
Thank you for your helpful comment. Now they will understand that they need to remove repetitive code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

export default function Button() {

    const [section, setSection] = useState('Home')

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log("render on state change")
    },[section])

    function home() {
        setSection('Home')
    }
    function about() {
        setSection('About')
    }
    function help() {
        setSection('Help')
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={home}>Home</button>
                    <button onClick={about}>About</button>
                    <button onClick={help}>Help</button>
                </div>
                <p>{section}</p>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

**Explanation:**
Now here in this case console will be logged only when state is changed and only once when page is reloded.
Once the page is reloaded, it will log messages  once after that it will not log message until you change the value of your state.

hope you got what actually is happening.
comment below if still there's problem.

Comment: i suggest you to read react doc.

Comment: You are right...but i don't want solutuion of this problem, I only want why console message is printed for the second time clicking on the about button, when component only render for the first time(i, e, during state changes to "Home" from "About")? Got it??

Comment: answer is in your question bro, component is rendered whenever state is updated. when you clicked on about first time it changes from "home" to "about" here in case 1.  

Now in case 2: when you again clicked on about button again state is changed but this time state stored the same data value which is "about" so, in both condition state is changed but in case 1 it changed it's value from "home" to "about" and in case 2 it changed it's value from "about" to "about" in both cases state is updated. and according to react component will render whenever state is updated.

Comment: No, this is wrong, You can check by clicking about button more than one time, it actually re-rendered for two times after that the component doesn't renders...
 I have found the real answer in 
https://youtube.com/clip/Ugkxqedv-8YA3cUc5PMLCRJHzJrJEUfjK4Hs
Codevolution is the great channel I have ever found...

Comment: ok at the end you found the answer.

Comment: Hmm....Javascript is confusing but React js is 1000000x confusing for me buddy....

Comment: lol after couple of years you will say........ the same thing lol. hey do you wanna join discord

Answer (score 0):

It is really nice to understand the difference between component rendering and mounting. The difference is that React re-renders the component every time there is a change in the state, and that's why the console.log is printing. To avoid this, you can write your console.log function in the useEffect hook. The useEffect hook only runs one time when the component is mounted.